# How to save redux store objects to external JSON file..?

Tags: json, reactjs, object, react-redux, immutable.js

I am having `redux store` as `object key value` pairs as given below:

```
{
  "appElements": {
    "layers": {
      "layer_1": {
        "scene": {
          "width": "100px",
          "height": "100px",
          "bgColor": "#aaaaaa",
          "bgImage": "http:bgimage1.png"
        },
        "items": {
          "yrgroih9": {
            "width": "100px",
            "x": "200px"
          },
          "qhy0dukj": {
            "width": "100px",
            "x": "200px"
          },
          "7lw2nvma": {
            "width": "100px",
            "x": "200px"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using [Immutable Js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) and the above data stored as Immutable `Map` data type into store.

**Below image shows the state structure for better understanding:**
[image]

I need to save the above given **store values** into **external json file**, for example `mysavedfile.json`.

Code used in react reducer:

```
import { Map, fromJS, isImmutable } from 'immutable';

export default function images(state = new Map(), action) {
  switch (action.type) {

    case 'ADD_LAYERS':
      return fromJS({ appElements:action.data.appElements });

    case 'STATE_TO_JSON_FILE':
      console.log("state");
      //Here i need to do code to save state to external json file.

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

How to achieve this..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to create a file directly on your computer's file system as this would be a huge security risk. You cannot do this from a web page using JavaScript.

You could write a server side service to post your state to and it creates a file - you may then download the file or be content with where your server side stores it.

You could alternatively create a file in memory and prompt a user download - for more answers like this see [Create a file in memory for user to download, not through server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server)

Comment: Can i use redux axios to make post call to my local php server..? If any code sample will helpful to me..

Comment: sounds reasonable. I haven't used axios - i'd suggest creating a separate question for this with the axios tag

Comment: @ArunValaven you can make a post request and send all the store data on that route and then inside of that request you could write data onto the file. You might wanna check this for axios https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#axios-api. Send all of your data inside the data section of the request.

Comment: @ShubhamJain... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your reducers should be pure and create a new state based on the action. To export the state as a JSON you should use selectors.

Comment: 1. So the given reducers is not pure.? 
2. Already state created as given above. 
3. How to use selectors..?
Please give your one sample code or any website link to save store as json file.

Answer (score 0):

**HACK SOLUTION**: Example from my **REAL project**! Save Redux store objects to external JSON file.

**STEP-1** import useStore first from react-redux and then getState() function is used to access store state.

**STEP-2** area is the name of my slice in Redux store and areaName is state in that slice.

**STEP-3** FiletoSave variable is used to export JSON file with data from store.

```
import { useStore } from "react-redux";

const exportJsonFileFromStore = () => {

const store = useStore();
const FileSaver = require('file-saver');    
    
function exportData() {
   
    const filename = 'filter_settings';

    let prepareObject = {       // It is used to make a JSON object 
      areaName:store.getState().area.areaName  ,   
    }
    const fileToSave = new Blob([JSON.stringify(prepareObject)], {
        type: 'application/json'
    });
    // this will save file
    FileSaver.saveAs(fileToSave, filename);
}

return (
  
        <button onClick={(event: any) => exportData()}>Click me to download!</button>
   
)
```

}